# Constructing an example of a cyclic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_5$ of degree $6$ and ramification index $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

As the title says, I would like to find an example for a cyclic field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}_5$ with $[K:\mathbb{Q}_5]=6$ and $e(K/\mathbb{Q}_5)=3$.

Because this implies that the intertial degree of $K/\mathbb{Q}_5$ must be $2$, the extension $K_0 = \mathbb{Q}_5(\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q}_5$ (where $\zeta_3$ is a primitive third root of unity) is unramified of degree $2$.

Now I only need to find an element $\alpha$ such that $K=K_0(\alpha)/K_0$ is totally ramified of degree $3$. As this extension must be cyclic (because it has prime degree), the element $\alpha$ must satisfy $\alpha,\alpha^2 \not\in L_0$ but $\alpha_3 \in L_0$. Or one could say that the polynomial $x^3 - \alpha^3$ is irreducible over $L_0[x]$.

I wanted to give $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$ a try (i.e. $\alpha^3 = 2$) and noted that $x^3-2$ has the root $3$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$. This only says that if $\sqrt[3]{2} \in K$, then $K/K_0$ is indeed totally ramified. But this still says nothing about whether $x^3-2$ is irreducible over $K_0[x]$ or not.

Could you please guide me finishing my example?

Comment: Are you sure it is $5,3,6$ ?

Comment: Have you tried looking for a degree $3$ Eisenstein polynomial in $\mathbb Q_5(\zeta_3)$? Since the extension is unramified, you know that $5$ is still a uniformiser.

Comment: As for your example, since $x^3 - 2$ has a root in $\mathbb F_5$, by Hensel's lemma, it already has a root in $\mathbb Q_5$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 There is no cyclic extension as in the title, the only Galois extension of ramification 3 and degree 6 is $\Bbb{Q}_5(5^{1/3},\zeta_3)$ which is not abelian.

Comment: Oh - I missed the cyclic condition! In the body of the question, the OP only said they want to find a field extension. Presumably it should be $5, 2, 6$.

Comment: @reuns: Oh, I was not aware that this is not possible. Could you maybe elaborate on why $\mathbb{Q}_5(5^{1/3},\zeta_3)$ is the only Galois extension of ramification index 3 and degree 6? And its Galois group is $S_3$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The result alluded to in reuns' comment can be found in Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory*, Proposition II.5.12: Let $K$ be a complete, discretely valued field with perfect residue field, and let $p \geq 0$ be the characteristic of the residue field. Let $E/K$ be a field extension that is totally ramified (meaning the degree $[E : K]$ is equal to the ramification index $e$) and tamely ramified (meaning $e$ is not divisible by $p$). Then there exist uniformizers $\pi \in K$ and $\Pi \in E$ satisfying $\Pi^e = \pi$, and so $E \cong K(\pi^{1/e})$.

Thus, if $K$ is any unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_5$ and $E/K$ is totally ramified with $e = [E : K]$ coprime to $p$, then $E \cong K((u \cdot 5)^{1/e})$ for some unit $u \in \mathcal{O}_K^\times$. If we allow wild ramification ($p \mid e$), then there are many more possible extensions, but the possibilities for tamely ramified extensions of local fields are very restricted.

Comment: You meant $\Pi^e = \omega \pi$ with $\omega $ a root of unity, I'm struggling to check if $\omega $ has (or doesn't have) to be in $\Bbb{Q}_5$ because our extension is Galois of degree $6$. Anyway if our extension was abelian then $\Bbb{Q}_5(5^{1/3},\zeta_3,\omega^{1/3})$ would be abelian which is a contradiction because $\Bbb{Q}_5(5^{1/3},\zeta_3)$ is not abelian.

Comment: Right, I think I mixed up the order of quantifiers there, I'll fix that.

Comment: @DanielHast: I don't understand what $E \simeq K((u \cdot 5)^{1/e})$ tells us. Would you mind explain it? I have not really understood the essence of your argument.

Comment: @Rotdat: The point is that $E$ is of the form $K(\pi^{1/e})$ for a uniformizer $\pi \in K$, whose Galois closure over $K$ is $K(\pi^{1/e}, \zeta_e)$, which is a cyclic extension of $K$ if and only if $\zeta_e \in K$. But note that $\mathbb{Q}_5$ doesn't have a cube root of unity, so the extension isn't cyclic in your case.